# How to reuse brace expansion?

Tags: sh, brace-expansion

I need to cleanup a bunch of directories and put some files in them e.g.,

```sh
#!/bin/sh
rm -rfv {a,b,c}
mkdir {a,b,c}
touch {a,b,c}/foo.txt
```

This works fine but I'd like to avoid hardcoding directories in too many place. Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
DIRS=a,b,c
rm -rfv {$DIRS}
mkdir {$DIRS}
touch {$DIRS}/foo.txt
```

Is this possible using brace expansion?

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine

Firstly, one has to say that brace expansion is **not** part of a POSIX shell. You have `#!/bin/sh` shebang and brace expansion *will not work* on many platforms. Use `#!/bin/bash` or other shell that supports the features you use.

> How to reuse brace expansion?

Just use bash arrays.

```
dirs=({a,b,c})
# or dirs=(a b c) ...
mkdir "${dirs[@]}"
foos=(); for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do foos+=("$i"/foo.txt); done
touch "${foos[@]}"
# or
printf "%s/foo.txt\n" "${dirs[@]}" | xargs -d'\n' touch
```

> Is this possible using brace expansion?

You can `eval` everything and as usual `eval` is one letter away from "evil".

```
eval "anything {$DIRS}/foo.tx"
```

Notes: Prefer to use lowercase variables in your scripts, use uppercase for exported variables.